# PHP exec - how do I correctly escape strings in the command?

Tags: python, php, exec

I'm working on a simple project to remote control some GPI stuff on a Pi.
Where I am stuck is I can't figure out how to properly escape my $foo & $bar variables in my kill command.

```
<?php
$foo = "thing1";
$bar = "thing2";

// this works and I am starting a python script and then letting it run in the background
$output = `nohup /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/scripts/$foo-$bar.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &`;

// doing a ps-eaf from the shell, I see the script running with the correct value
// for the vars.
//
// trying to kill the script I started. The below code doesn't work. suspect I need to 
// escape my vars, but how ?

exec('nohup pkill -f \'/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/scripts/$foo-$bar.py\' > dev/null 2<&1');

?>
```

Comment: You just have to use double quotes in your call to `exec()` because php wont replace `$foo` and `$bar` in single quoted strings. So it should be `exec("nohup pkill -f '/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/scripts/$foo-$bar.py' > dev/null 2<&1")` See [the manual](https://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) for reference.

Comment: Since you mention escaping, you might also want to read about [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: @Sherif That was it! Thank you.